# split a string using find_if

Tags: string, iterator, split, c++

I found the following code in the book "Accelerated C++" (Chapter 6.1.1), but I can't compile it. The problem is with the `find_if` lines. I have the necessary includes (vector, string, algorithm, cctype). Any idea?

Thanks, Jabba

```
bool space(char c) {
    return isspace(c);
}

bool not_space(char c) {
    return !isspace(c);
}

vector<string> split_v3(const string& str)
{
    typedef string::const_iterator iter;
    vector<string> ret;
    iter i, j;

    i = str.begin();
    while (i != str.end())
    {
        // ignore leading blanks
        i = find_if(i, str.end(), not_space);

        // find end of next word
        j = find_if(i, str.end(), space);

        // copy the characters in [i, j)
        if (i != str.end()) {
            ret.push_back(string(i, j));
        }
        i = j;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: How about those compile errors? :)

Comment: Indeed.  Throwing in the includes and `using namespace std;` makes it compile flawlessly here; please show us what is different for you.

Comment: This example compiles here. You should give a complete minimal example.

Comment: I pasted the complete class to <http://pastebin.com/faf27525>. The error message is pasted here: <http://pastebin.com/m39c9bbdb>. A short extract from the error:

../src/Split2.cpp:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘find_if(Split2::split_v3(const std::string&)::iter&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’

As I'm new here and this is my 1st post, I don't know if there is a pastebin-like service here. I didn't want to send in too much garbage.

Comment: You should have edited your question to include those details.

Comment: This is the book's mistake, not yours, but note that the parameter to `isspace` isn't a char, it's an int, and the value of it must be representable as an unsigned char (or may be EOF). Suppose that your char has value 0xFE, and char is signed in your implementation. When implicitly cast to int, that's -2, which is not representable as an unsigned char (nor is any other negative number). The easy way around this is to cast to unsigned char before using isspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in the code you posted. There is a very obvious problem with the **real** code you linked to: `is_space` and `space` are *member* functions, and they cannot be called without an instance of Split2. This requirement doesn't make sense, though, so at least you should make those functions **static**.

(Actually it doesn't make much sense for split_v3 to be a member function either. What does having a class called Split2 achieve over having just a free function - possibly in a namespace?)

Comment: To work around this: use a struct as a predicate instead of a function. This way you still get "encapsulation" if you declare it as an nested class.

Comment: You are right, if I put them in a class, those functions must be static. I prefer putting everything in classes (I used Java before). Is it a bad habit?

Thanks for the answers, the problem is solved.

Comment: pmr: could you post an example for that?

Answer (score 2):

Writing this in a more STL-like manner,

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class P, class T>
void split(const string &str, P pred, T output) {
    for (string::const_iterator i, j = str.begin(), str_end = str.end();
            (i = find_if(j, str_end, not1(pred))) != str_end;)
        *output++ = string(i, j = find_if(i, str_end, pred));
}

int main() {
    string input;
    while (cin >> input) {
        vector<string> words;
        split(input, ptr_fun(::isspace), inserter(words, words.begin()));
        copy(words.begin(), words.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: minor point, but `using namespace std;` should be avoided imho.

Comment: I normally avoid `using namespace` too, but for this short example I preferred to avoid over-80 column lines.

Answer (score 1):

As requested:

```
class SplitV2 {
 public:
  void foo();
 private:
  struct space { bool operator() (char c) { return isspace(c); } };
  struct not_space {
    Split2::space space;
    bool operator() (char c) { return !space(c); }
  };
```

Use them with `std::find_if(it, it2, space())` or `std::find_if(it, it2, not_space()`.
Notice that not_space has a default constructed space as a member variable. It may be not wise to construct space in every call to `bool not_space::operator()` but maybe the compiler could take care of this. If the syntax for overloading operator() confuses you and you would like to know more about using structs as Predicates you should have a look at operator overloading and some guidelines to the STL.

Comment: Why bother with `space` and `not_space` when you can use `ptr_fun(isspace)` and `not1(ptrfun(isspace))` from `<functional>`?

Comment: Because as stated `isspace` (from <cctype>) expects an `int` convertible to an `unsigned char` which is error-prone. This way you neatly wrap the difficulty so that it's easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Off hand, I would say it should probably be

```
i = str.find_if( ...
j = str.find_if( ...
```

Comment: Nope, `template<class InputIterator, class Predicate> InputIterator find_if(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Predicate pred);` is an inline function acting on iterators defined in `<algorithm>` -- not a method on strings or vectors or anything like that.